# How do I control SDK version used to build project in ASP.NET Core project while using Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-core, aspnet-compiler

I created a new ASP.NET Core project using Visual Studio 15.8 Preview 5.0 and the project is .NET Core 2.1.2 based.

The preview version of VS ships with a preview version of .Net Core, but I want to use a release version of the SDK to compile the source.

I tried adding a global.json file in the project directory of my web application proj, but it is not respecting that version that I declared.

So how do I control which version of the SDK is used to compile my project?

Comment: Try placing the global.json file in the same directory as the solution file.

Comment: Yeah! That did the trick!